# Looking for the best way to download a data file, create txt file from data and send to AWS S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

The title explains it but I'm using Net::SFTP to logon and get the 2 data files from the secure FTP. I then want to create a file from the downloaded data unless it's already created and I just need to skip `File.open` and send to AWS s3?

Here's the code so far. I'm a junior Rails developer and this has not been refactored. It's also not quite working yet. I'm all set up for Amazon::AWS::s3 but need the methods to send.

```
class MissouriJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
  end


  def entries(sftp)
    downloads = []
    date_time = Time.new.inspect
    entries = sftp.dir.entries('/Distribution/dor/modlpool_daily/')
    entries.each_with_index do |entry, index| 
      # File.open("public/missouri_data/#{entry.name}_#{date_time}.txt", "w")
      downloads << sftp.download!("/Distribution/dor/modlpool_daily/#{entry.name}")
      file = File.open("#{entry.name}_#{date_time}", "w+") { |f| f.write("#{downloads[index]}") }
      byebug 
    end 
  end

  def logon 
    sftp = Net::SFTP.start('moftp.mo.gov', Rails.application.credentials[:missouri_username], password: Rails.application.credentials[:missouri_password] )
    entries(sftp)
  end

end
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Is it how to download multiple files via Net::SFTP? Or how to combine two files into one file? Or how to upload a file (the combined file) to S3? Or all of the above? It's quite easy to find an example of using Ruby to upload to S3. For example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html

Comment: Why don't you use aws-sdk?

Comment: I am using `aws-sdk`. I just can't figure out how to convert the above code to sending directly to S3.

Comment: Specifically, instead of `sftp.download('<path to sftp> server', '<path to local folder>'), I'm using `sftp.download!('<path to sftp>")` to save into a variable called `download`. The problem is that `download` is just an integer, not the whole object.